# SELECT MIN and MAX across fields and aggregate by user

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, rails-postgresql

I have the following raw data saved in the db

```
id  min_price, max_price, min_x, max_x, user_id
-------------------------------------------
 1    50        200       5      null     1
 2    0         100       0      3        1
 3    150       300       0      null     1
 4    20        200       2      5        2
 5    50        200       0      5        2
 6    150       200       1      3        2
```

I want to create a sql query (postgres) with the following data:

```
min_price, max_price, min_x, max_x, user_id
    0         300       0     null   1
    20        200       0      5     2
```

so basically i would get the min and max for each user_id for difference fields, where null should take precedence over the actual max value,
any idea on how to achieve this via sql?

Comment: It's always annoyed me that `1 + 2 + 3 + NULL` is `NULL`, but `sum()` of a set of rows containing the same values is `6`.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if NULL exists within that column using COUT(*) vs. COUNT(column):

```
SELECT 
   user_id,
   CASE WHEN COUNT(*) <> COUNT(max_x) THEN NULL ELSE MAX(max_x) END AS max_x
FROM vt
GROUP BY 1
```

A brute force solution would be:

```
NULLIF(MAX(COALESCE(max_x, 9999999999)), 9999999999)
```